# When I select a window by using mouse cursor it doesn't really works

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, ubuntu-gnome

I'm using two monitors so that I have my desktop extended. It works fine except that when I select other window by using the mouse cursor it doesn't really select it, in a way that if I start writing it will write on the old window and not in the current selected one.

I'm using gnome.

Can anyone help me?

I appreciate,

Agnello

Comment: I found a solution. On the 'Tweak Tool' on 'Windows' option on 'Focus Mode' I selected the option 'Mouse'